# Null reference at dataset row count

Tags: c#

Here is my count. Trying to check row count at of dataset but getting the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object at if
>   (ds.Tables["GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumber"].Rows.Count
>   != 0).

Please help.

```
 using (SqlCommand GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberSP = new SqlCommand("GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberSP", Apptestconn))
 {
     GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberSP.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", "nguyenlc");
     GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseStatus", TextBox1.Text);
     GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseNumber", CaseNumberTextBox.Text);
     GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberSP.ExecuteNonQuery();

     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberSP);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds, "GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberTable");
     ReviewCaseStatusListView.DataSource = ds.Tables["GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberTable"];
     ReviewCaseStatusListView.DataBind();

     if (ds.Tables["GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumberTable"] != null)
     {
         if (ds.Tables["GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumber"].Rows.Count != 0)
         {
             CaseUploadHistoryLabel.Text = "Case Upload History:";
             CaseUploadHistoryLabel.Visible = true;
          }

      }
}
```

Comment: is `Rows` null in that context?  That's about all it could be for the code you have.

Comment: ds.Tables["GetCaseInformationByCaseStatusANDCaseNumber"] would be null, there's no table with this  name in the Dataset and then when to call Rows on Null to get the RowCollection you get an exception

Comment: Thanks Mrinal. I debuged but still for some reason didn't see this.